# MvvmCross ViewPager not show in Activity

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I want to show a few tabs sharing the same viewmodel with viewpager in an activity. I am using MvvmCross 5.6.2.

When I do that in a fragment, the viewpager is shown properly. Using the same method, I add tab fragments to the viewpager in an activity with code like this:

```
        var viewPagerFragmentList = new List<MvxViewPagerFragmentInfo>
                {
                    new MvxViewPagerFragmentInfo("Personal", typeof (SettingPersonalFragment), ViewModel),
                    new MvxViewPagerFragmentInfo("Preference", typeof (SettingPreferenceFragment), ViewModel)
                };
        viewPager.Adapter = new MvxCachingFragmentStatePagerAdapter(this, SupportFragmentManager, viewPagerFragmentList);

        var tabLayout = FindViewById<TabLayout>(Resource.Id.tabs_fragment_setting_viewpager);
        tabLayout.SetupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

The tab fragments are not shown on screen, though the tab fragment's OnCreate and OnCreateView are executed.

I found the latest sample Playground is showing tabs in activity too. Following the sample, I register the fragment:

```
    [MvxTabLayoutPresentation(TabLayoutResourceId = Resource.Id.tabs_fragment_setting_viewpager, ViewPagerResourceId = Resource.Id.viewpager_fragment_setting_viewpager, Title = "Personal", ActivityHostViewModelType = typeof(SettingViewModel))]
```

No luck with that. The last thing I found in Playground to show a tab is to navigate to the fragment viewmodel:

```
    _navigationService.Navigate<Tab2ViewModel>();
    _navigationService.Navigate<Tab3ViewModel>();
```

However, in my case, I do not have a viewmodel for each fragment. The workaround on my hand is to move the viewpager to a fragment in the activity.

How could I show the viewpager fragments without their own viewmodels in an activity?

Thanks,

Nick

Comment: You could refer to this sample : https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Samples/blob/master/XPlatformMenus/XPlatformMenus.Droid/Fragments/Android%20Specific/ExampleViewPagerFragment.cs

Comment: York. The sample you mentioned hosts the viewpager in a fragment, not activity. There is no issue to do that in a fragment. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see any reason why it wouldn't work for the ViewPager being located in the Activity. I recommend you to keep trying that alternative. The Playground TestProject has that scenario covered in TabsRootView/TabsRootViewModel https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/develop/TestProjects/Playground.

Can you maybe share with us some code for your Activity?

Comment: nmilcoff, I did check the Playground sample. It shows the tab fragment with navigating to the tabviewmodel as I mentioned above. It needs a viewmodel for each tab but I have a single viewmodel for all tabs. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above code that works in fragment also work in activity. There is an issue in the xml causing the viewpager not showing. Sorry.

Thanks everyone who helped.